# Templates constructor

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Trying to write templated constructor class for exceptions, so I can put variable length argument when throwing exception and came to sth like this:

```
namespace miniReader{

    namespace Exception{

        template<typename deriverEx, typename baseType>
        class Exception : public baseType{
            std::string errorClass;
            mutable std::string exStrMsg;
        protected:
            static  std::stringstream exMsg;
            std::string whatMessage;
           // Exception(const Exception& other): baseType(""){}

            const char* what() const noexcept{
                if(exStrMsg.empty()){
                    exStrMsg = exMsg.str();
                }
                exMsg.str("");
              return exStrMsg.c_str();
            }

            ~Exception() noexcept {
            }
        public:
            Exception(): baseType("") {
            }
        };

        class miniRuntimeException : public Exception<miniRuntimeException, std::runtime_error>{
        public:
            miniRuntimeException(): Exception() {}

            template<typename T, typename...Args>
            miniRuntimeException(T first, Args...arg): Exception(){
                LOG(first, this);
                exMsg << first << " ";
                miniRuntimeException(arg...);
            }
        };

    template<typename deriverEx, typename baseType>
    std::stringstream  Exception<deriverEx, baseType>::exMsg;

    }
}
```

Now I can write throw exception like this:

```
 miniRuntimeException(__FILE__, __LINE__, "Failed opening file", "Runtime Exception")
```

I have made exMsg static on purpose since in other case I could get all template arguments to it. So my problem is that exMsg in Exception class is static so when derived class constructor is called(variadic template) read arguments are correct. I cannot find a way to make it non static since exMsg will get only one template argument. Is there a way to do this? Next question is when my template constructor is called, for every argument new object is created(is that correct?) and how in this case i can pass information between those objects, like update exMsg so it will be complete in final object?

Comment: Your question in general is not very clear...

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question (after reading it 3 times). I suggest replacing the chain of constructors with following code (inheritance omited for the sake of clarity):

```
class miniException {
    std::stringstream msg;
public:
    template<class... ARGS> miniException(ARGS... args) {
       populate_msg(args...);
    }
private:
    template<class T, class... ARGS> void populate_msg(T t, ARGS... args) {
        msg << t << " ";
        populate_msg(args...);
    }
};
void populate_msg() { }
```

P.S. You might actually want to accept arguments by const reference instead of a value.

Comment: Thanks, thats worked. Wonder why Exception class need explicit copy constructor:  *Exception(const Exception& other): baseType(""){LOG("Copy constructor");}*   However its is never called, and when it is not provided i get error:   *error: use of deleted function ‘std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_stringstream(const std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’* Thanks

Comment: Because `std::basic_stringstream` does have a copy constructor declared deleted. Being called or not called does not really matter, since compiler generates defalt copy ctor for your exception class. You should actually define yours as deleted too, instead of creating a dummy one.

Comment: Thanks for responses, wanted to tick You're answers as useful but don't have enough reputation unfortunate.

Comment: @user3655463, I am glad it helped :)